# How to convert timezone string to time zone offset using moment?

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I have timezones saved for each user as "Europe/Bucharest" or "Europe/New York".

However angular only accept timezone offset string: "+0400" or "-0330" when passing the value as a filter to the dates.

How can I convert those  strings to a timezone offset string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you've installed the [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) library:

```js
(function ()
{
    var app = angular.module("app", []);

    function HomeController()
    {
        var vm = this;
        vm.europe = moment().tz('Europe/Bucharest').format("ZZ");
        vm.us = moment().tz('America/New_York').format("ZZ");
    }

    app.controller("HomeController", [HomeController]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.4/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Angular JS App</title>        
    </head>
    <body>

         <div class="container" ng-controller="HomeController as homeCtrl">
            <h4>Europe: {{homeCtrl.europe}}</h4>
            <h4>America: {{homeCtrl.us}}</h4>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Updated to support exactly angularjs way timezone. If this is what you were looking for, plz mark as answer. Thanks!